# KeyId is 0 for PgpPublicKeyEncryptedData

Tags: c#, .net-core, encryption, bouncycastle, pgp

When I'm reading the encrypted file to understand with which public key it has been encrypted for, for some reason the `KeyId` property is 0.

Here's the code I've been using so far, which has worked, I have no idea why now when I feed it some encrypted files, it returns a 0 in that field:

```
using Stream decoderStream = PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(encryptedData);
var objectFactory = new PgpObjectFactory(decoderStream);
var encryptedList = (PgpEncryptedDataList)objectFactory.NextPgpObject();
string keyId;
byte[]? key;
foreach (PgpPublicKeyEncryptedData keyData in encryptedList.GetEncryptedDataObjects())
{
    long keyId = keyData.KeyId // This is 0 for some reason?
}
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

The keys were encrypted by using GPG, so I decided to take a look at my gpg's configuration and see if I messed something up.

As it turns out, I did. I hardened my configuration to not include the key id's when a message is encrypted, by specifying the following command in my `gpg.conf` file:

`throw-keyids`

After I removed that out of the way, everything started working as expected.